# Can you make contractions in this way?

Tags: contractions

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

"When you jog is a great time to listen to audio books." --> "When you jog's a great time to listen to audio books."

"The way I hear you talk to your coworker is not appropriate in this setting." --> "The way I hear you talk to your coworker's not appropriate in this setting."

"The way you talk is funny." --> "The way you talk's funny."

"Each day we waste is a day we can never get back." --> "Each day we waste's a day we can never get back."

Can you structure sentences using contractions in this way?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107807/discussion-on-question-by-mark-morales-ii-can-you-make-contractions-in-this-way).

Answer (score 1):

"Contraction" in writing is used to indicate when portions of words would be elided in the corresponding speech.  Anywhere that the speaker might reasonably elide some sounds you can denote that with an apostrophe where the omitted characters would go.  There are no "rules", other than one should attempt to avoid sequences that are unnecessarily confusing and ambiguous.

Comment: There absolutely are rules — what do you think the following's: an *is* at the end of a sentence can never be contracted.

Comment: @PeterShor -  Yeah, but no one would pronounce it that way in corresponding speech and so you wouldn’t write it that way either.

Comment: @Jim: Right. At least for informal writing, which I am fairly sure is what we're talking about here, the rules of written contractions are the same as the rules for contraction in speech, which I think means all the OP's sentences are at least marginally acceptable. But there are rules.

Answer (score -2):

No, because the contraction can only be applied to the subject. "The way you talk is funny." can't have any contraction because "The way" is the subject related to "is", not "talk". "The way I hear you talk to your coworker is not appropriate in this setting" has the subject "the way" for "is", not "coworker".The same applies to the sentence "Each day we waste is a day we can never get back." because the subject is "Each day", not "waste". If there's something after the subject, you can't contract. The first sentence has another problem, because you didn't type the subject "it" before "a great time". There is an "is" without a subject. A verb always needs a subject and "When you jog" has the subject "you", but you left "is" subjectless.

Comment: The subject of the sentence "when you jog is a great time ..." is "when you jog".